# Replaced monitor. Now during boot - screen blanks (Revivable with cable re-connect)

Tags: boot, screen

I have been using my Ubuntu 22.04.2 machine for a fairly long time without issues.
All this time I had a very old monitor that has 1080p resolution at 60Hz.
That old monitor was connected to Intel CPU's (11th gen) integrated GPU via DisplayPort.

Recently I changed to a new monitor which is capable of 4K at 144Hz.
I had set its resolution to 1440p and 120Hz.

But whenever I power on the PC then I am able to see Ubuntu OS/Kernel loading, but then the screen blanks (all I can see is a black screen) and I get a monitor's message about a lost signal.
(Note that I passed the phase of GRUB.)

So I disconnect the DisplayPort cable and then I connect it again - which makes the screen to appear without issues.
Conclusion: The issue isn't with the Graphic Driver (I don't need to update this).

I don't want to re-connect my DisplayPort connection every time.
I prefer to understand what is the issue and fix it, such that every boot sequence is properly displayed on the monitor.

I had read several resources online (URLs referred below), but I don't think that these are necessarily related to me issue, except maybe for the GRUB entry options which replaces "quiet splash" with "nomodeset".
Also I don't want to change anything "just to try if it works" because it might break something.

I prefer to understand what is the issue in my case - for example by reading an error in the logs - and only later after verifying the issue - then I will apply its solution.

My GPU driver is - according to "lspci -vv":

```
"Kernel driver in use: i915"
```

Is there something I could check to understand the root cause of this issue?

*Related Resources*:

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

https://www.yosoygames.com.ar/wp/2022/11/my-ubuntu-linux-boots-into-a-black-screen-guide/

[How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers)

https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-black-screen-solution

http://ubuntuguide.net/no-input-signal-and-boots-into-blank-screen-after-ubuntu-installation

https://www.stephenwagner.com/2019/05/05/ubuntu-linux-black-screen-frozen-system-after-upgrade-install/

Comment: Replace the changes you did to your `grub` config with the original settings, run `update-grub`, check again. When it fails tell the exact contents of `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: @Luuk Which changes to `grub`? I didn't do any changes to grub configs for a long time. Is there a specific file you want me to show? Thank you.